# Cannot get pages except main of Vue App while running in Docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx

I have an application, consisting of 3 components: flask backend, Vue frontend and nginx server to connect them. Unfortunately, when I start app up in Docker, I have an access only to main page /, others are completely blank.

nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default ssl;
    server_name _;


    # ssl on
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/private.pem;

    location / {
      proxy_pass        http://ui:8080;
    }

    location /api {
      proxy_pass        http://flask:5001;
    }
}
```

nginx dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

RUN apk --update --no-cache add openssl

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY /default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Vue dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20
RUN npm install -g http-server
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

And finally docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    nginx:
        build:
            context: ./nginx
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        depends_on:
            - flask
            - ui
    
    flask:
        build: ./
        ports: 
            - 5001:5001

    ui:
        build: ./ui
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080
```